# Kong DNS resolution failed without default gateway

Tags: nginx, kong

I am attempting to send a request to endpoint `/v1/resource`, and I am getting the following error:

```
2021/06/02 23:17:17 [crit] 30#0: *2963 connect() failed (101: Network unreachable), context: ngx.timer, client: 172.13.0.21, server: 0.0.0.0:8443
2021/06/02 23:17:18 [crit] 30#0: *2969 connect() failed (101: Network unreachable), context: ngx.timer, client: 172.13.0.21, server: 0.0.0.0:8443
2021/06/02 23:17:19 [crit] 30#0: *2988 connect() failed (101: Network unreachable), context: ngx.timer, client: 172.13.0.21, server: 0.0.0.0:8443
2021/06/02 23:17:20 [crit] 30#0: *3007 connect() failed (101: Network unreachable), context: ngx.timer, client: 172.13.0.21, server: 0.0.0.0:8443
2021/06/02 23:17:21 [crit] 30#0: *3039 connect() failed (101: Network unreachable), context: ngx.timer, client: 172.13.0.21, server: 0.0.0.0:8443
2021/06/02 23:17:21 [crit] 30#0: *3053 connect() failed (101: Network unreachable), context: ngx.timer, client: 172.13.0.21, server: 0.0.0.0:8443
2021/06/02 22:16:27 [error] 30#0: *29609 [lua] balancer.lua:1064: execute(): DNS resolution failed: dns lookup pool exceeded retries (1): failed to create a resolver: failed to set peer name: network unreachable. Tried: ["(short)my.hostname.com:(na) - cache-miss","my.hostname.com:33 - cache-miss/scheduled/try 1 error: failed to create a resolver: failed to set peer name: network unreachable/scheduled/try 2 error: failed to create a resolver: failed to set peer name: network unreachable/dns lookup pool exceeded retries (1): failed to create a resolver: failed to set peer name: network unreachable","my.hostname.com:1 - cache-miss/scheduled/try 1 error: failed to create a resolver: failed to set peer name: network unreachable/scheduled/try 2 error: failed to create a resolver: failed to set peer name: network unreachable/dns lookup pool exceeded retries (1): failed to create a resolver: failed to set peer name: network unreachable","my.hostname.com:5 - cache-miss/scheduled/try 1 error: failed to create a resolver: failed to set peer name: network unreachable/scheduled/try 2 error: failed to create a resolver: failed to set peer name: network unreachable/dns lookup pool exceeded retries (1): failed to create a resolver: failed to set peer name: network unreachable"], client: 172.13.0.21, server: kong, request: "GET /v1/resource HTTP/1.1", host: "my.hostname.com"
172.18.0.11 - - [02/Jun/2021:23:17:22 +0000] "GET /v1/resource HTTP/1.1" 500 42 "-" "curl/7.29.0"
```

It complains that i cannot resolve `my.hostname.com`, however, when I exec into the Kong docker, I am able to successfully get a response, and able to ping `my.hostname.com` successfully.

```
bash-5.0# nslookup my.hostname.com
Server:     172.13.0.1
Address:    172.13.0.1:5

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   my.hostname.com
Address: 172.13.0.21

Non-authoritative answer:
```

And ping:

```
bash-5.0# ping my.hostname.com
PING my.hostname.com (172.13.0.21): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.13.0.21: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.065 ms
64 bytes from 172.13.0.21: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms
64 bytes from 172.13.0.21: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
```

The issue can be fixed if a default route is added, however, on our setup this is not possible and this should work because all services are localhost.

```
bash-5.0$ kong version
2.4.1
```

`nginx.conf`:

```
charset UTF-8;
server_tokens off;

error_log /dev/stderr debug;

lua_package_path       './?.lua;./?/init.lua;;;;';
lua_package_cpath      ';;;';
lua_socket_pool_size   30;
lua_socket_log_errors  off;
lua_max_running_timers 4096;
lua_max_pending_timers 16384;
lua_ssl_verify_depth   1;

lua_shared_dict kong                        5m;
lua_shared_dict kong_locks                  8m;
lua_shared_dict kong_healthchecks           5m;
lua_shared_dict kong_process_events         5m;
lua_shared_dict kong_cluster_events         5m;
lua_shared_dict kong_rate_limiting_counters 12m;
lua_shared_dict kong_core_db_cache          128m;
lua_shared_dict kong_core_db_cache_miss     12m;
lua_shared_dict kong_db_cache               128m;
lua_shared_dict kong_db_cache_miss          12m;

underscores_in_headers on;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;

# injected nginx_http_* directives
client_body_buffer_size 8k;
client_max_body_size 0;
lua_shared_dict prometheus_metrics 5m;
lua_ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_dhparam /usr/local/kong/ssl/ffdhe2048.pem;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_session_tickets on;
ssl_session_timeout 1d;

init_by_lua_block {
    Kong = require 'kong'
    Kong.init()
}

init_worker_by_lua_block {
    Kong.init_worker()
}

upstream kong_upstream {
    server 0.0.0.1;

    # injected nginx_upstream_* directives

    balancer_by_lua_block {
        Kong.balancer()
    }
}

server {
    server_name kong;
    listen 0.0.0.0:8000 reuseport backlog=16384;
    listen 0.0.0.0:8443 ssl http2 reuseport backlog=16384;

    error_page 400 404 405 408 411 412 413 414 417 494 /kong_error_handler;
    error_page 500 502 503 504                     /kong_error_handler;

    access_log /dev/stdout;
    error_log  /dev/stderr debug;

    ssl_certificate     /usr/local/kong/ssl/kong-default.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/kong/ssl/kong-default.key;
    ssl_certificate     /usr/local/kong/ssl/kong-default-ecdsa.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/kong/ssl/kong-default-ecdsa.key;
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_certificate_by_lua_block {
        Kong.ssl_certificate()
    }

    # injected nginx_proxy_* directives
    real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
    real_ip_recursive off;

    rewrite_by_lua_block {
        Kong.rewrite()
    }

    access_by_lua_block {
        Kong.access()
    }

    header_filter_by_lua_block {
        Kong.header_filter()
    }

    body_filter_by_lua_block {
        Kong.body_filter()
    }

    log_by_lua_block {
        Kong.log()
    }

    location / {
        default_type                     '';

        set $ctx_ref                     '';
        set $upstream_te                 '';
        set $upstream_host               '';
        set $upstream_upgrade            '';
        set $upstream_connection         '';
        set $upstream_scheme             '';
        set $upstream_uri                '';
        set $upstream_x_forwarded_for    '';
        set $upstream_x_forwarded_proto  '';
        set $upstream_x_forwarded_host   '';
        set $upstream_x_forwarded_port   '';
        set $upstream_x_forwarded_path   '';
        set $upstream_x_forwarded_prefix '';
        set $kong_proxy_mode             'http';

        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_buffering          on;
        proxy_request_buffering  on;

        proxy_set_header      TE                 $upstream_te;
        proxy_set_header      Host               $upstream_host;
        proxy_set_header      Upgrade            $upstream_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header      Connection         $upstream_connection;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For    $upstream_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto  $upstream_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Host   $upstream_x_forwarded_host;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Port   $upstream_x_forwarded_port;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Path   $upstream_x_forwarded_path;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Prefix $upstream_x_forwarded_prefix;
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass_header     Server;
        proxy_pass_header     Date;
        proxy_ssl_name        $upstream_host;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_pass            $upstream_scheme://kong_upstream$upstream_uri;
    }

    location @unbuffered {
        internal;
        default_type         '';
        set $kong_proxy_mode 'unbuffered';

        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_buffering         off;
        proxy_request_buffering off;

        proxy_set_header      TE                 $upstream_te;
        proxy_set_header      Host               $upstream_host;
        proxy_set_header      Upgrade            $upstream_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header      Connection         $upstream_connection;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For    $upstream_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto  $upstream_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Host   $upstream_x_forwarded_host;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Port   $upstream_x_forwarded_port;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Path   $upstream_x_forwarded_path;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Prefix $upstream_x_forwarded_prefix;
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass_header     Server;
        proxy_pass_header     Date;
        proxy_ssl_name        $upstream_host;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_pass            $upstream_scheme://kong_upstream$upstream_uri;
    }

    location @unbuffered_request {
        internal;
        default_type         '';
        set $kong_proxy_mode 'unbuffered';

        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_buffering          on;
        proxy_request_buffering off;

        proxy_set_header      TE                 $upstream_te;
        proxy_set_header      Host               $upstream_host;
        proxy_set_header      Upgrade            $upstream_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header      Connection         $upstream_connection;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For    $upstream_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto  $upstream_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Host   $upstream_x_forwarded_host;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Port   $upstream_x_forwarded_port;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Path   $upstream_x_forwarded_path;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Prefix $upstream_x_forwarded_prefix;
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass_header     Server;
        proxy_pass_header     Date;
        proxy_ssl_name        $upstream_host;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_pass            $upstream_scheme://kong_upstream$upstream_uri;
    }

    location @unbuffered_response {
        internal;
        default_type         '';
        set $kong_proxy_mode 'unbuffered';

        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_buffering         off;
        proxy_request_buffering  on;

        proxy_set_header      TE                 $upstream_te;
        proxy_set_header      Host               $upstream_host;
        proxy_set_header      Upgrade            $upstream_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header      Connection         $upstream_connection;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For    $upstream_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto  $upstream_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Host   $upstream_x_forwarded_host;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Port   $upstream_x_forwarded_port;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Path   $upstream_x_forwarded_path;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Prefix $upstream_x_forwarded_prefix;
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass_header     Server;
        proxy_pass_header     Date;
        proxy_ssl_name        $upstream_host;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_pass            $upstream_scheme://kong_upstream$upstream_uri;
    }

    location @grpc {
        internal;
        default_type         '';
        set $kong_proxy_mode 'grpc';

        grpc_set_header      TE                 $upstream_te;
        grpc_set_header      X-Forwarded-For    $upstream_x_forwarded_for;
        grpc_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto  $upstream_x_forwarded_proto;
        grpc_set_header      X-Forwarded-Host   $upstream_x_forwarded_host;
        grpc_set_header      X-Forwarded-Port   $upstream_x_forwarded_port;
        grpc_set_header      X-Forwarded-Path   $upstream_x_forwarded_path;
        grpc_set_header      X-Forwarded-Prefix $upstream_x_forwarded_prefix;
        grpc_set_header      X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        grpc_pass_header     Server;
        grpc_pass_header     Date;
        grpc_ssl_name        $upstream_host;
        grpc_ssl_server_name on;
        grpc_pass            $upstream_scheme://kong_upstream;
    }

    location = /kong_buffered_http {
        internal;
        default_type         '';
        set $kong_proxy_mode 'http';

        rewrite_by_lua_block       {;}
        access_by_lua_block        {;}
        header_filter_by_lua_block {;}
        body_filter_by_lua_block   {;}
        log_by_lua_block           {;}

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header      TE                 $upstream_te;
        proxy_set_header      Host               $upstream_host;
        proxy_set_header      Upgrade            $upstream_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header      Connection         $upstream_connection;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For    $upstream_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto  $upstream_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Host   $upstream_x_forwarded_host;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Port   $upstream_x_forwarded_port;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Path   $upstream_x_forwarded_path;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Prefix $upstream_x_forwarded_prefix;
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass_header     Server;
        proxy_pass_header     Date;
        proxy_ssl_name        $upstream_host;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_pass            $upstream_scheme://kong_upstream$upstream_uri;
    }

    location = /kong_error_handler {
        internal;
        default_type                 '';

        uninitialized_variable_warn  off;

        rewrite_by_lua_block {;}
        access_by_lua_block  {;}

        content_by_lua_block {
            Kong.handle_error()
        }
    }
}

server {
    server_name kong_admin;
    listen 0.0.0.0:8001;

    access_log /dev/stdout;
    error_log  /dev/stderr debug;


    # injected nginx_admin_* directives
    client_body_buffer_size 10m;
    client_max_body_size 10m;

    location / {
        default_type application/json;
        content_by_lua_block {
            Kong.admin_content()
        }
        header_filter_by_lua_block {
            Kong.admin_header_filter()
        }
    }

    location /nginx_status {
        internal;
        access_log off;
        stub_status;
    }

    location /robots.txt {
        return 200 'User-agent: *\nDisallow: /';
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what may cause this issue, can kong operate without network? or if there is a setting that is needed to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS resolving is done by using UDP request/response actions or TCP connections. Both require that the system can send packets to the IP address of the DNS resolver.

In order to do that, one needs to have a route defined at least to the name server.

In your case, you would need to have a route to `172.13.0.21`.

Comment: But how does `nslookup` and `ping` to `172.13.0.21` work without the route defined? All services are on the same box.

Comment: Are you sure the program that gives DNS resolving error is running inside that Docker container? Also, if it is nginx making the request, make sure you have correct nameserver configuration in its configuration file.

Comment: Yes, the logs were generated from the docker logs on the container. How would the nameserver configuration look to allow it to correctly proxy the request?

Comment: Also, the weird thing is when a default route is added nginx is able to proxy the request. note: our box doesn't not have connectivity to the network.